# ARKit: Virtual objects fixed to camera frame when placing multiple objects outdoors

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

While placing objects on a plane using ARKit, when the total number of objects is more than one, sometimes the objects remain fixed to the camera frame and are not actually rendered in the real world scene. I'm guessing that this could be due to certain external factors such as lighting, [feature points](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2887449-rawfeaturepoints), quality of the real world plane, etc. Has anyone else encountered this or know of a way to fix this or a work around to prevent this? Thanks!

Edit: Here is some code that handles the rendering of the objects:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.virtualObjectInteraction.updateObjectToCurrentTrackingPosition()
        self.updateFocusSquare()
    }

    if objectsViewController != nil {
        let planeAnchor = focusSquare.currentPlaneAnchor
        objectsViewController?.updateObjectAvailability(for: planeAnchor)
    }

    // If the object selection menu is open, update availability of items
    if objectsViewController != nil {
        let planeAnchor = focusSquare.currentPlaneAnchor
        objectsViewController?.updateObjectAvailability(for: planeAnchor)
    }

    // If light estimation is enabled, update the intensity of the directional lights
    if let lightEstimate = session.currentFrame?.lightEstimate {
        sceneView.updateDirectionalLighting(intensity: lightEstimate.ambientIntensity, queue: updateQueue)
    } else {
        sceneView.updateDirectionalLighting(intensity: 1000, queue: updateQueue)
    }
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
    updateQueue.async {
        for object in self.virtualObjectLoader.loadedObjects {
            object.adjustOntoPlaneAnchor(planeAnchor, using: node)
        }
    }
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    updateQueue.async {
        if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
            for object in self.virtualObjectLoader.loadedObjects {
                object.adjustOntoPlaneAnchor(planeAnchor, using: node)
            }
        } else {
            if let objectAtAnchor = self.virtualObjectLoader.loadedObjects.first(where: { $0.anchor == anchor }) {
                objectAtAnchor.simdPosition = anchor.transform.translation
                objectAtAnchor.anchor = anchor
            }
        }
    }
}

func setTransform(_ newTransform: float4x4,
                  relativeTo cameraTransform: float4x4,
                  smoothMovement: Bool,
                  alignment: ARPlaneAnchor.Alignment,
                  allowAnimation: Bool) {
    let cameraWorldPosition = cameraTransform.translation
    var positionOffsetFromCamera = newTransform.translation - cameraWorldPosition

    if simd_length(positionOffsetFromCamera) > 10 {
        positionOffsetFromCamera = simd_normalize(positionOffsetFromCamera)
        positionOffsetFromCamera *= 10
    }

    if smoothMovement {
        let hitTestResultDistance = simd_length(positionOffsetFromCamera)

        // Add the latest position and keep up to 10 recent distances to smooth with.
        recentVirtualObjectDistances.append(hitTestResultDistance)
        recentVirtualObjectDistances = Array(recentVirtualObjectDistances.suffix(10))

        let averageDistance = recentVirtualObjectDistances.average!
        let averagedDistancePosition = simd_normalize(positionOffsetFromCamera) * averageDistance
        simdPosition = cameraWorldPosition + averagedDistancePosition
    } else {
        simdPosition = cameraWorldPosition + positionOffsetFromCamera
    }

    updateAlignment(to: alignment, transform: newTransform, allowAnimation: allowAnimation)
}

func placeVirtualObject(_ virtualObject: VirtualObject) {
    guard let cameraTransform = session.currentFrame?.camera.transform,
        let focusSquareAlignment = focusSquare.recentFocusSquareAlignments.last,
        focusSquare.state != .initializing else {
        return
    }

    let focusSquareScaleInverse = 1.0 / focusSquare.simdScale.x
    let scaleMatrix = float4x4(uniformScale: focusSquareScaleInverse)
    let focusSquareTransformWithoutScale = focusSquare.simdWorldTransform * scaleMatrix

    virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject = virtualObject
    virtualObject.setTransform(focusSquareTransformWithoutScale,
                               relativeTo: cameraTransform,
                               smoothMovement: false,
                               alignment: focusSquareAlignment,
                               allowAnimation: false)

    updateQueue.async {
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(virtualObject)
        self.sceneView.addOrUpdateAnchor(for: virtualObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check apple sample code  you can use that code as ref.

Comment: There are many reasons why this could be happening.  Post your code.

Comment: If you post some code we can help